# What happens to a thread executing a method as target

Tags: python, multithreading

I use some multi-threading in my python application. I want to know what happens to a thread object after it finishes executing the "target" python method. Is it destroyed?

```
def speak():
    #codes

thread = threading.Thread(target=speak, args=())
thread.start()
```

Comment: Don't forget that the `Thread` instance is not the real thread. The actual thread is an operating system construct, while the `Thread` instance is the handle that you use to inquire about, and modify the state of the OS thread. It makes sense that the Python object would persist after the OS thread is gone because (a) your program potentially still holds references to it, and (b) how else is your program going to be able to _ask_ whether the OS thread still exists or not?

Comment: I got your point.  So I need to del(thread) if the thread is not use again. Otherwise it will be in the memory until the main program finishes the execution. @Solomon Slow

Comment: OK, but also don't forget that `thread` is not the `Thread` instance.  `thread` is a _variable_ that holds a reference to the thread instance, and `del(thread)` operates on the variable, not on the instance.  Python will automatically destroy the instance and free up the memory that it occupied when the last reference to it is lost. So, `del(thread)` will destroy the instance if _and only if_ `thread` is your program's only reference to it.

Comment: OK. It was quite helpful. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple test shows that the thread is still in memory, "stopped" after it finishes its process:

```
import threading

def speak():
    pass

thread = threading.Thread(target=speak, args=())
thread.start()
thread.join() # wait for the process to finish;

print thread

# Result: <Thread(Thread-1, stopped 21864)>
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html):
"Python’s Thread class supports a subset of the behavior of Java’s Thread class; currently, there are no priorities, no thread groups, and threads cannot be destroyed, stopped, suspended, resumed, or interrupted."

Comment: To delete the thread entirely, you'd have to do: `del(thread)`